# Get module.exports from within the same file

Tags: javascript, module, node.js, commonjs

In a file I have this code:

```
module.exports.greet = function() {...}
```

I want to use that function from within the same file.

I thought this would work:

```
this.greet()
```

But it didn't.

What is the reference I have to use?

Comment: Just wanted to ask whether my answer about the environment varaible was helpful to you, otherwise this might be a bug which should be filed :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally, this should work just fine, but let's see why this might fail.

**Some Background first**
What happens is that `exports` is an object that, along with a few other things like `require`, `module`, `__dirname` etc. ,  gets passed into the closure that wraps the modules contents, `exports` is then returned by `require()`.

See: https://github.com/ry/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L327

`this` inside the module refers to the `exports` object, the `module` object then holds a reference to the `exports` object. The name space inside the module is provided via the closure.

In the end there's also the `global` object which provides the global name space and hosts things like `process`.

**Examples**

```
// main.js
this.bla = function(){} // sets bla on the the exports object
require('./sub');
console.log(this); // { bla: [Function] }
console.log(exports); // { bla: [Function] }
console.log(module); /* { id: '.',
                          exports: { bla: [Function] },
                          parent: undefined,
                          filename: '/home/ivo/Desktop/main.js',
                          loaded: false,
                          exited: false,
                          children: [] } */

// sub.js
this.greet = function() {} // sets greet on the exports object
console.log(this); // { greet: [Function] }
console.log(exports); // { greet: [Function] }
console.log(module); /* { id: './sub',
                          exports: { greet: [Function] },
                          parent: 
                          { id: '.',
                            exports: { bla: [Function] },
                            parent: undefined,
                            filename: '/home/ivo/Desktop/main.js',
                            loaded: false,
                            exited: false,
                            children: [] },
                         filename: '/home/ivo/Desktop/sub.js',
                         loaded: false,
                         exited: false,
                         children: [] } */
```

**Cause of the problem**
The only explanation for the fact that your code doesn't work is that the environment variable `NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS` was set to an integer bigger than zero.

In this case the modules get run in their own context. `this` inside the main module will now refer to the `global` object and inside sub modules, it will refer to a **sandbox** object. Therefore `this.foo` will not set any property on the `exports` object.

See: https://github.com/ry/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L98
And: https://github.com/ry/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L296

**Fixing the problem**
You can check the environment variables that were passed to the node process:

```
console.log(process.env); // get a list of all variables

// get just the one that's causing trouble, if this returns a number > 0 then it's in effect
console.log(process.env['NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS']);
```

In case that `NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS` is in effect, you need to check your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` files for something like `export NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS=1;` and remove it.

Make sure to open up a new terminal, since changes those two files are only read in when one is created.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue! How you reference the variable in other files is similar to how you have to reference it here.

try

```
 modules.exports.foo ...
```

within the file to access that variable.

```
exports.foo ...
```

should also work!